# Bouncycastle Decrypt PKCS8

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am having difficulties decrypting a string using Bouncycastle. I suspect its the encoding but I cant find any PKCS8 encoding for bouncycastle

```
var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Input);

            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;
            var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

            using (var txtreader = new StringReader(privateKey))
            {
                keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

                decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
            }

            var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
            return decrypted;
```

This is the PKCS8 Format RSA Key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

[This is the error code I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLh6.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use AsymmetricKeyParameter instead of AsymmetricCipherKeyPair, like this:

```
    AsymmetricKeyParameter akp;

    var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

    using (var txtreader = new StringReader(privateKey))
    {
        akp = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

        decryptEngine.Init(false, akp);
    }
```